# SQL Query Activity Data Extension Values are Case-sensitive?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, sql, case-sensitive

Are Data Extension values case sensitive when querying with SQL query activity?

I found this to be the case when querying `WHERE Status = 'Active'` that it ignored records with a status value of "ACTIVE".

I suppose I could use `WHERE Status LIKE LOWER ('Active')`, but I had no idea that querying the data extension values were case sensitive. Anyone else come across this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the SQL Server back-end is not case-sensitive.

Per the [**official docs**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_sql_reference.htm&type=5):

> SQL support for the SQL Query Activity is based on SQL Server 2005 capabilities.

(I believe the infrastructure is now newer than SQL Server 2005)

Also in the Filter documentation about [**operators**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_data_extension_operators.htm&type=5):

> Search strings are not case-sensitive.

Also per Michael Clark at SF, [**subscriber keys are case-insensitive**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/80262).

Additionally, as far as I know, these are the only places in SFMC that are case-sensitive:

- File naming patterns used in Data Extract and File Transfer Activities in Automation Studio
- Server-Side JavaScript code

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to a doc or something? I don't doubt your answer, but given the original question, I think having some documentation that backs your answer would be helpful.

Comment: Duh, of course.  It'd be nice if it was specifically called out on in the query documentation -- other than the server version.  Perhaps someone who knows officially can weigh in.

Comment: Thanks @AdamSpriggs. I could've sworn it excluded all caps values but when I went to replicate it, I wasn't able to replicate. Thanks for confirming!